# Should we have a canonical question about Android batteries?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

I struggled for a while reading [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/50469/16265) where the OP was asking for a consistent answer about the Android battery, battery calibration and battery usage.

He pointed out several answers from different users that present a conflict on advices on how should an Android user proceed with battery maintenance and usage.

The question raised on my head after reading this was:

```
Are we giving the appropriated information about battery usage and maintenance?
```

that in turn lead me here to discuss this matter, because if we've got contradictory information, some one is wrong or the specifics of each situation require a more careful explanation about the battery maintenance and usage.

---

Should we have a canonical question e.g.:

## How do I take care of the battery of my device?

I believe *for now*, that this question would have an answer covering each scenario, or a single answer pointing to individual already existent answers for each scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Good point, I shared (and still share) Zuul's concern. Alternative to a question/answer summing up things and pointing to the corresponding answers, this summary could be **placed in the corrsponding tag-wikis** ([calibration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calibration), [battery](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battery)), including links to each other and to the corresponding questions – as it is already done for many other topics ([lost-phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lost-phone), [backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backup) to name some examples).

I know this still leaves the question I raised earlier: how can we draw more attention to the tag wikis. I often encounter questions even using the correct tags, where the answer is given in the tags' wiki already. But as with duplicates, some users tend to go straight asking their questions without doing any search either. The big advantage of placing such information in the corresponding tag wikis is: it makes it easy to find, without having to use a search at all. For this reason, even if decided for a "canonical question/answer", this should at least be linked to from the corresponding tag (as we should do for the [update](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/update) tag and the "how do I update my device [to Android x.y.]" questions, to make them easier to find.

Comment: Btw: I just created the [calibration tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/calibration/info) and then wanted to update the [battery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/battery/info), finding it already holds the information Zuul's question is about :D So I've just linked the "new question" there, as it sums up the "battery calibration" questions.

Comment: *Ducks for cover on question about AOSP vs AOKP*

Comment: @geffchang same suggestion, yes: [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info). I will see to link it there :)

Comment: I think the question is reasonable though, as it also considers its relationship to the stock ROM. @t0mm13b's answer also clarifies the confusion between stock ROM and AOSP, which some people are not aware of.

Comment: Sure, I never said differently (and meanwhile it's linked from the [rom tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom/info)). But what does this have to do with the battery (i.e. this question here where you commenting on the answer)? ;)

Comment: Ah, yes. I am off-topic now.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is out of our domain.  Most of this is really about the physical properties of batteries in general, and not Android or Android device batteries specifically.

I also think a lot of the conflicting answers are due to the fact that different batteries (even of the same type, like lithium ion) respond differently to different charge and discharge strategies.  And manufacturers certainly do things differently on a hardware level to interact with the battery.  So I don't think there is an appropriate canonical answer to be had.